# Bitwise C Operation

Tags: c

when x = 1
what should 
`! x | x` 
supposed to be?
I am really confused as what I did it:
x = 1 = 01 in binary,
  `!x = 10` 
   `!x | x` = 11 = 3in decimal.

But it should be 1. (Even try going hexadecimal (something lengthy but what I am learning as an undergrad), I got -1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` is the *logical* negation operator. If you give it nonzero things it gives you back a zero. If you give it a zero it gives you back 1.

So

```
   !x | x
=> !1 | 1
=> 0 | 1
=> 1
```

Note how this is different from the *bitwise* negation operator, `~`. If you had used this instead of `!`, things would have worked out like this (assuming 8-bit values, you can scale up to 32 or 64 or whatever):

```
   ~x | x
=> ~1 | 1
=> 11111110 | 00000001
=> 11111111
=> -1
```

It all comes down to understanding the difference between `!` and `~`. It's not obvious; it's just something you have to get used to. Just as a reminder

```
!7 = !23423523 = !46 = !(-200) = !1 = 0
```

For any nonzero `x`, `!x = 0`. That's just how it is. The idea behind that is C takes 0 as false and anything else as true. So, since a value like 70343 or 1 counts as true, applying `!` to it gives false, or 0.

Answer (score 1):

the `!` operator is for logical negation, `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0` for both numeric and pointer types.

`!x` has type `int` and a value of `1` if `x` compares equal to `0` and has a value of `0` for all other cases.